# Im making many objects one model, while still looking like many different Objects, How would I do that?

Tags: modeling

Basically I have 3 different objects that are not touching, but I want to make them into a model like that, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Join them together.

Select the first initial object by right clicking on it then subsequently selecting the rest (by right clicking on them) while holding the shift key. Once each object that you want in the same object is selected, press CTRL+J.

(This is all assuming you have left the key shortcuts their default values.)

Comment: to add more of object to you selection, you should "shift-right click" on them... you can also use other selection tools, like ctrl-c or ctrl-b, or others...